# Interference When Installing Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, installation, bsod

I had several problems on my old pc, so I decided to reinstall Windows XP. The problem is, when it copies the files, I get a lot of errors with Windows XP setup cannot copy file, so I ignore all of them, as enter will not do. Then, when it finishes copying, I get a blue screen of death with the error `BAD_POOL_CALLER`, with technical information :

> STOP 0x000000C2 (0x00000007, 0x00000CD4, 0x00000000, 0xE1EE38E8).

I tried to install from another windows cd and I got the same errors. What should I do? It all started when Windows XP was updating and I accidentally took the PC off the switch. What should I do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: sounds like the hard drive might be the issue. could be RAM, but my first guess would be a bad hard drive

Comment: If your PC's motherboard supports the boot from USB then it will good idea to boot from USB. Or you can use Linux Live CD to check out the disk errors. Most probably it is the HDD issue.

Comment: @steve I don't really understand. I was thinking it could be from DVD RW, so i replaced it, but i got the same problems with the second one as well. But, after the computer restarted, after xp files where copied (some of them were not), i got a fatal system error : 

STOP: c000021a {Fatal System Error}
The Session Manager Initialization system process terminated unexpectedly with a status of 0xc000026c (0x00000000 0x00000000). 
The system has been shut down.

If it is a problem of HDD or RAM, how could i find out which one, without having to use another ram/HDD as replacement?

Comment: @EkaAnggraini I think you should have to switch the RAM one by one and check out if it works and for HDD I think you can run a `chkdsk` to connect it on other PC.

Comment: But in my opinion this is due to bad HDD sectors or the disk you have used to install the XP are corrupted. Try out the fresh disk.

Comment: @steve Ok i will try it, i replace the xp disk and cd drive, but i got no better results. It remains RAM, hard disk and motherboard. Is there a way to check if RAM of hard disk are having a problem without replacing them? Also, could it be from processor? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @EkaAnggraini its not steve its me who is suggesting you to do so. Processor should not the problem. But I'll suggest to run `chkdsk` for our HDD by connecting it on other PC

Comment: @avirk oh sorry i have done wrong to you. thanks for your suggestion and I must try it, chkdsk

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3894/discussion-between-avirk-and-eka-anggraini)

Answer (score 0):

windows xp copies files to your hard drive before attempting install. if your hard drive is bad it would fail to copy consistently, and in the process break the install

Comment: I think you should have to improve your answer to help out the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The `BAD_POOL_CALLER` bug check that you've received has a value of 0x000000C2. This indicates that the current thread is making a bad pool request.

You can refer to the [MSDN WIndows - Bug Check 0xC2: BAD_POOL_CALLER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to identify the codes that you've received.

**I would say that you either have:**

- some external device connected that's causing the error
- bad ram modules

**e.g.,** *Removing a USB device without using the `Safely remove USB devices` can be sufficient to get that error.*

---

**Some Guidance:**

1. Disconnect all external devices (printers, USB devices, etc...) and then boot up.

   If this corrects the issue, connect the devices one at a time until you discover the piece of hardware causing the issue. An updated driver\software for the device should fix it.
2. Use the `Last known good configuration` from the Windows Advanced Options menu.

   If this option resolves the issue then look for any recent updates, or recently installed software that may have caused this problem.
3. Boot to Safe Mode from the Windows Advanced Options menu.

   If you can enter windows using `safe mode`, the issue is most likely related with a driver or software.

   From within Safe Mode run a System Restore. ([article with instruction here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306084))
4. Perform a Clean Boot.

   Step by Step article to troubleshoot with a [Clean Boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310353). Also, an [Advanced troubleshooting Guide!](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316434)

---

As I've recommend on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/441976/94664), you should use an [Ubuntu live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) to boot and run some tests on your computer.