# Weirdness after Windows operating system reinstall

Tags: windows, installation, bsod

I have reinstalled my OS succesfully. I have turned off and restarted a few times and it was fine. A few hours later, when I turned it on, there was an error on the screen:

> Windows could not start because the following file is missing or
>   corrupt:
>
> ```
> \WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CONFIG\SYSTEM
> ```
>
> You can attempt to repair this file by starting Windows Setup using
>   the original Setup CD-ROM. Select 'R' at the first screen to start
>   repair.

So I intended to repair it by reinstalling all over again.I boot to the Windows installation CD:

> Press any key(with blue background)
>
> text below:
>
> - Setup is loading files (windows executive)
> - Setup is loading files (hardware abstraction layer)

I was waiting for half an hour, and nothing changed. I repeated the process several times and still nil.

Please give advice and solutions about where the problem is. Is it with the hardware, Windows CD, or both?

Comment: You could have fixed the original issue fairly simply by copying over the backup registry hive (which is what was the original issue) - However, please update your question with OS/hard drive details - its impossible for us to help very effectively otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that you are having a **hard drive failure**.

An Ubuntu LiveCD may be able to diagnose your problem for certain.  [Zuul's answer](https://superuser.com/a/441976/83694) addresses other diagnosis possibilities and options.

If so, you should purchase a new hard drive or perhaps consider a [solid-state drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive), if one interests you.  Unless you have data elsewhere on the drive, a freshly installed operating system is not worth salvaging, so you should dispose of the drive (i.e. turn it into an ashtray, mail it to me, throw it away).

Matching symptoms:

- Windows XP was able to boot successfully, but not after some reboots.
- Blue Screen of Death
- A critical boot file suddenly goes inaccessible.

(Windows XP was identified by "`Setup is loading files (hardware abstraction layer)...`".)

Comment: Remember that the windows setup loads the files to the memory, only after having the files loaded, further into the setup process, it reaches the hard drive!

Comment: @Zuul: +1 to your answer then!

Comment: @Zuul: Hey, same computer?: http://superuser.com/questions/441810/interference-when-installing-windows-xp  This means that my hard drive failure explanation is plausible.

Comment: I've updated my reading on the subject from that other question (to be sure), and by the Microsoft Forums, and documentation, it is very much related with external devices or a driver/software update that went wrong or doesn't work properly. But yes, your answer never left the "plausible" side, I've just pointed out that if the computer gets errors long before starting using the HDD, for sure the HDD is not causing that particular error(s)... But can be responsible by others errors latter on.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely is an hardware issue, to be specific, RAM.

The mentioned file / file structure is the one most used when windows is being used, thus being the first to go when the system is running over a bad RAM module.

Another indication is the fact that when you tried to install windows again, the setup can't perform properly.

**e.g.,**

> With windows 7 setup, the black screen mentioning several files at the bottom, while presenting a message like "Windows is loading files...", means that the setup if loading each one of those files into the computers RAM modules.
>
> Continuing, all the way until it asks you about your hard drive, being this the first time that the windows setup interacts with your HDD, and starts writing to it.

So, all points to a bad RAM module, and I strongly recommend that you test the RAM modules present on that computer (I use memtest and it works great):

[memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/)

[memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion for me, 
but what might be due to optical is weak? 
because I rarely use the cd / dvd room ... 
I'm confused 
but at least I already know why such a possibility

Comment: You mentioned that the error appeared after a few restarts, so, it as nothing to do with your CD/DVD drive. If it was a bad copied file, you would have the error sooner. You can try an Ubuntu Live CD, it really stresses the CD / DVD drive when loading... that way you can check that new issue as well.

Comment: oh well, i must try your suggestion (I will try Ubuntu Live CD for my computer), thank you..